# python-paramiko - run command in background

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

If I use command `ssh -f server 'cp /file1 /file2 & >/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; disown;'` it detaches well and command is runned in the background. But is there any variant of -f key for paramiko?

Comment: Have you tried to run the paramiko statements that you need in a separate thread or process?

Comment: I use it from django and don't want to use threads.

Comment: Have you considered using [celery](http://celeryproject.org/)?

Comment: I need as less 3rd-party software as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create new thread/process, for example using Python `threading` module. Paramiko has to write to socket after finishing Django request.